# Get a Blank Web Page when opening certain sites

Tags: dns

I get a blank web page when I try to open certain websites. I am not sure why this happens.

I am able to access these sites using an anonymous proxy though.

Either it has to be an issue with my ISP's DNS Server or the Web Server itself is filtering the request.

I have tried accessing the site using a Perl Script as well and again the same response. Tried with different browsers, same response.

For instance, when I try to open the site, http://imgbox.com

I get a blank page in response.

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html><head<title></title></head><body> <!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser--> </body></html>
```

However, I am able to access this site via a proxy.

Also, I was able to open the site imgbox.com properly a few days ago without a proxy.

I am able to ping the site as well.

Where could the problem be?

I have even tried setting my Primary DNS Server to the Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8 but again the same problem.

Comment: what is the OS your using? did you flush the DNS cache? Did you look at the source code on the proxied web page?  Different browsers use different "failed" pages, and they can be configured also, is the "blank" different than your usual "cant get to the website" type page? What is the whole of your connection path, like modem only router, wireless? The one site you listed has activeX on it, could that be related somehow? Got another one that breaks?

Answer (score -1):

More than likely, your service provider (or anyone in your network path) are running some sort of filtering tool.  A quick Google search shows that imgbox.com hosts adult content so this is likely the case.

Simply changing your DNS server doesn't necessarily avoid a content block (though in some cases it does).  Both DNS and web traffic is commonly intercepted invisibly (DNS for filtering, web for caching and/or filtering).  This can be done anywhere in your path to the Internet (at your home router, at your ISP, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Only two possibilities but to narrow things down if you can, change your IP Address by resetting your modem (verify its changed) and see if you can access imgbox now.  If you can it means the site is blocking your IP.  Of course if it still doesnt work it doesnt mean they aren't blocking you since they can still block a whole network but at least it tells us something.

Very likely though you were hosting content they deemed unacceptable and have blocked your IP so by changing it you should be back up and running.