# Site shows blank page, but not with proxy

Tags: browser, proxy

I am attempting to access the popular site, [Deposits.org](http://www.deposits.org). When I go there, I get a blank page. When I view source, that is also completely empty. But I'm able to see the site through an anonymous proxy, such as KProxy.com .

I have not seen this problem with any other site.

I tried accessing the site in every browser I have: Firefox, IE, and even the "Create PDF from Web Page" feature in Acrobat. All result in a blank page.

I looked at my cookies in Firefox, and there are none from Deposits.org.

I cleared the browser cache in Firefox.

I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit. My Firefox is up-to-date. My access is via a WiFi router plugged into a modem connected to Time Warner. I don't have access to the modem to see if a connection without the router has the same problem.

I [cleared my DNS cache](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+To+Clear+Your+DNS+Cache).

This is the same problem as described in the SuperUser question, [Get a Blank Web Page when opening certain sites](https://superuser.com/questions/624805/get-a-blank-web-page-when-opening-certain-sites) , but the site in question there was apparently a porn site, which Deposits.org is not. It was that question posting that gave me the idea to try a proxy.

The proxy is a sufficient workaround, so the problem is not critical. But it's strange, and I'd like to understand what's happening.

Comment: Although this is happening on a different site, this is exactly identical to http://superuser.com/questions/624805/get-a-blank-web-page-when-opening-certain-sites

Comment: This is a representative from Deposits.org, feel free to email us at our contact page so we can help you resolve this problem. We can then investigate on why you cant access it and whether its a specific country, IP range that has been blocked. regards

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Yes, and if you read my question, you'll find that I link to that question in it.

Comment: any answer applicable to that question would also apply here.